# Trying to understand eigenvalues with respect to differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-in-odes

I am trying to understand how to find eigenvalues from a matrix consisting of exponential terms, considering a differential equation. The examples I've seen online are ODEs. Without using a vector with exponential terms, here is what I have learned.

$$\dfrac{d}{d t}\overrightarrow{x}(t)=\lambda \overrightarrow{x}(t)$$

$$\dfrac{d}{d t}
\begin{bmatrix}
\ x_1(t) \\
\ x_2(t) \\
\ x_3(t) 
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\ \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\
\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\ x_1(t=0) \\
\ x_2(t=0) \\
\ x_3(t=0) 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Here is what I am trying to understand

[Section of a paper with imag eigenvalue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpAzc.png)

In this paper, the following assumption is made.

$$\overrightarrow{J}(t)= \lvert \overrightarrow J \rvert e^{-i\omega t}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lvert J_x \rvert e^{-i\omega t} \\
\lvert J_y \rvert e^{-i\omega t} \\
\lvert J_z \rvert e^{-i\omega t} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

They are using partial derivatives (I believe this can be viewed as an ODE then?). Differentiating with respect to time I believe yields the following. Please correct me if I am wrong.

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\overrightarrow{J}(t) =\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}
\begin{bmatrix}
\lvert J_x \rvert e^{-i\omega t} \\
\lvert J_y \rvert e^{-i\omega t} \\
\lvert J_z \rvert e^{-i\omega t} 
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\ -i\omega & 0 & 0 \\
\ 0 & -i\omega & 0 \\
\ 0 & 0 & -i\omega 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lvert J_x \rvert e^{-i\omega t(t=0)} \\
\lvert J_y \rvert e^{-i\omega t(t=0)} \\
\lvert J_z \rvert e^{-i\omega t(t=0)} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Or

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}
\begin{bmatrix}
\lvert J_x \rvert e^{-i\omega t} \\
\lvert J_y \rvert e^{-i\omega t} \\
\lvert J_z \rvert e^{-i\omega t} 
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\ -i\omega & 0 & 0 \\
\ 0 & -i\omega & 0 \\
\ 0 & 0 & -i\omega 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lvert J_x \rvert  \\
\lvert J_y \rvert  \\
\lvert J_z \rvert 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Are my assumptions correct? If so, is there a deeper analysis to why this is the case with exponential terms?

Comment: What's the meaning of $|\cdot|$ ?

Comment: Your explanations are difficult to follow. Your final equation is wrong, as the dependency on time is gone from the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you want to know, but here is a short explanation about the relation between a system of linear ODEs and Eigendecomposition.

Assume a system of first order linear ODEs with constant coefficients. It can be written in matrix form:
$$\frac{d\vec x}{dt}=M\vec x.$$

Now assume an exponential solution of the form
$$\vec x=\vec ve^{zt}.$$

By plugging it in the equation, you get
$$z\vec ve^{zt}=M\vec ve^{zt}$$
which expresses that $z$ is an Eigenvalue of $M$, associated to the Eigenvector $\vec v$:
$$M\vec v=z\vec v.$$

So, after finding a diagonalization

$$M=T\Lambda T^{-1}$$
and setting
$$\vec x=T\vec y$$
the system reduces to
$$\frac{d\vec y}{dt}=\Lambda\vec y$$
which is a system of three easy *independent* equations

$$\frac{dy_k}{dt}=z_ky_k.$$ The initial conditions can be dealt with by using $\vec y_0=T^{-1}\vec x_0$.